# Node.js + Serve Static Files with RESTIFY

Tags: node.js, restify

I have a multi-level collection of .html, .js, .png, .css, etc files in a site. A peek at my site hiearchy looks like the following:

```
index.html
child1
  index.html
  page1.html
  page2.html
  ...
child2
  grandchild1
    index.html
  grandchild2
    index.html
  index.html
  page1.html
  page2.html
resources
  css
    myTheme.css
  img 
    logo.png
    profile.png
  js
    jquery.js
    ...
...
```

I am migrating this to run under Node.js. I have been told I MUST use RESTIFY. Currently, I've written the following for my server:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var fs = require('fs');
var mime = require('mime');

var server = restify.createServer({
    name: 'Demo',
    version: '1.0.0'
});

server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

server.get('/', loadStaticFile);

server.get('/echo/:name', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.params);
    return next();
});

server.listen(2000, function () {
    console.log('Server Started');
});

function loadStaticFile(req, res, next) {
    var filePath = __dirname + getFileName(req);
    console.log("Returning " + filePath);

    fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res.writeHead(500);
        res.end("");
        next(err);
        return;
      }

      res.contentType = mime.lookup(filename);
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end(data);

      return next();
    });
}

function getFileName(req) {
    var filename = "";
    if (req.url.indexOf("/") == (req.url.length-1)) {
      filename = req.url + "index.html";
    } else {
      console.log("What Now?");
    }
    return filename;
}
```

With this code, I can successfully load index.html. However, my index.html file references some JavaScript, image files, and style sheets. I can see via Fiddler that that these files are being requested. However, in my node.js console window, I never see "Returing [js|css|png filename]". Its like my node.js web server returns index.html and that's it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I fail to see the point in using `restify` if you are adding non ReST features like static file serving. `express` offers everything you need and more, with the addition of better docs, proven stability in production, and community support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do any of your served files contain relative paths (say `../abc.js`)?
You have to use `path.resolve()` to get the real path for `fs.readFile()`.

Anyway there are a lot of pitfalls in serving files:

- invalid url (400)
- file not found (404)
- escape sequence (url encoding)
- `fs.read()` read files into memory (by @robertklep)
- etc

You can use existing static file serving middleware.
I've been using [Ecstatic](https://github.com/jesusabdullah/node-ecstatic), AFAIK it handles those issues properly.

Try

```
server.use(ecstatic({ root: __dirname + '/' }));
```

If that fails you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13690887/665507) to stack Restify on top of Connect/Express.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to use static middleware (another issue with `fs.readFile` is that it reads files into memory first)

Answer (score 16):

The latest versions of restify has builtin middleware serveStatic() middleware that will do this for you.

from a http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#Server-API

```
server.get(/\/docs\/public\/?.*/, restify.serveStatic({
  directory: './public'
}));
```

for more detailed example:

http://mushfiq.me/2013/11/02/serving-static-files-using-restify/